# Localization not working on Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I can't get my app to work with localization.

- I have created a `Localizable.strings` file and ticked the languages that I am localizing. (For now I have base, english and spanish.)
- Localized storyboard with three languages.
- In Project settings > Info I checked <kbd>Use Base internationalization</kbd> and all languages are correctly added. (Moreover, beside the language it shows `2 Files Localized`, which I guess they must be the storyboard and .strings file.

I am using this example for testing:

```
self.loginLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"login", @"Login text info");
```

This is how the `Localizable.strings (Base)` file is looking like:

```
"login" = "Log in";
```

However, it is not working and instead it is showing `login`. Have I forgotten a key step?

BTW: I have tried already changing the `login` text just it case something was overriding the label.

Comment: I am a bit unsure of that. How could my application stop the localization system of xcode?

Comment: would be useful to see how the other languages string files look like

Comment: Have you added Localizations key in your's project info.plist file, if you have, could you check if the required "English" item is specified as one of its items?

Comment: @DanSpag - What do you mean? I have a included a library that has its own localization file. Can it be that library that is overriding everything? (The localization file is not called ``localizable.strings`` so I thought it could not be that library causing a problem.

Comment: @Idindu - I have not added anything to the info.plist file of my project. I just tried adding some keys and their equivalence just as if it was a localization file but also did not work. (I am not sure if you you meant this.)

Comment: When you have different localisations you will have more than one Localizable.strings file, one for each language; so I am saying it would be useful to see the content of the other files.

Comment: This [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014) helped me a lot and worked flawlessly.  Maybe try going through it to see what step you might be missing.

Comment: Are the ressources copied to the bundle ? Can you check if the content of the files is correct ? (Not sure if they are being processed or not).

Comment: I had the same exactly problem. My solution was check the key CFBundleDevelopmentRegion in the info.plist, I had some random text there that I replaced with a real region (United States, in my case) from the drop down recommended list.

Comment: In my case I have replaced the file name with default name `Localizable.strings`. Now it is working fine.In my project so many pods with language changes, so it is not reloading immediately, after second time reopening the app then it's working. So I have replaced with default file name `Localizable.strings`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the steps indeed, I don't think you've left anything out. I usually set the comment to nil instead of another NSString though - not sure if that makes a difference.

However, rather than in only base, make sure you're adding the same line also to the English and Spanish files (obviously translated as appropriate).

Next, for the language to show up, set the device to said language. Close your app and start it again. Strings should now show up in the other language.

Note that the Simulator often has trouble with new translations, especially when they've been added to an already deployed app. In that case, remove the app from the Simulator, click on Product - Clean, and re-deploy.

Comment: I tried cleaning the app and checked that all languages had the correct key and syntax, however, it is not working. I can't understand this.

Comment: Now it is working! So what I had to do is completely remove the application from the iOS Simulator. Apparently a clean (which is what I was always trying) is not enough for localizations to work.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it didn't work because the UILabel text was set as "Attributed" instead of "Plain" in the Attributes Inspector.

Localization with a .strings file doesn't seem to work on Attributed strings.

I even had a storyboard with mixed Plain and Attributed string labels, and the localization only worked on the Plain ones.

Comment: I had the same problem, with button why ? with another project it was "Plain" and translation works fine it's really ios thing :( lost a lot of time because of that

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having a similar issue in the future:

Check if your `*.strings` file has any non-printed characters.
I used JavaScript for a simple task and didn't realize it included some whitespace characters.

An easy way to check is to put the translation at the top of the file and see if it works. If it does, there might be some whitespace characters. The next steps are... binary search and remove the whitespace characters.